# Recursive C++ function calculation: Bn(a) = Bn−1(a) × Bn−2(a) where B1(a) = B2(a) = a

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out recursion for this specific program. I have tried a few different options, but I am brand new to recursive functions. The only part of the program I am allowed to modify is inside of the function B. 
This function calculates: Bn(a) = Bn−1(a) × Bn−2(a), where B1(a) = B2(a) = a.
So B1(a) = a  | B2(a) = a | B3(a) = a^2 | B4(a) = a^3 | B5(a) = a^5 | etc...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
float B(float a, int n)
{
   //Here is where I'm having an issue...
}
int main(void)
{ cout << "Input a float a, and an int n > 0: ";
   float a; int n;
   cin >> a >> n;
   cout << "B(" << a << ")_" << n << " = " << B(a,n) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you attempt to calculate `B(a,n-1)*B(a,n-2)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First take care of the cases where `n` is 1 or 2, which are defined to return `a` without recursing.  These are the so-called *termination cases*.

```
float B(float a, int n)
{
   if (n == 1 || n == 2) { return a; }

   // ...
}
```

Then you recurse for the others, subtracting from `n` each time:

```
float B(float a, int n)
{
   if (n == 1 || n == 2) { return a; }

   return B(a, n - 1) * B(a, n - 2);
}
```

If you pass in an `n` greater than 2, the recursive calls will eventually reach a termination case and execution will stop at that point, returning the final result all the way back up to the first call.

Let's take an example invocation, `B(2, 4)`.  This doesn't match the termination case, so the function will recurse, like so:

- `B(2, 4)` will return `B(2, 3) * B(2, 2)`.
- `B(2, 3)` will return `B(2, 1) * B(2, 2)`.  We replace this in the original, and we get: `(B(2, 1) * B(2, 2)) * B(2, 2)`.
- All we have left now is termination cases, so we can substitute those by the value of `a`: `(2 * 2) * 2` = 2<sup>3</sup> = 8.

As far as what actually happens (not just algebraic simplification), this will be the call tree:

- `B(2, 4)` is not a termination case, it will call:

  - `B(2, 3)` is not a termination case, it will call:

    - `B(2, 2)` is a termination case, returning 2.
    - `B(2, 1)` is a termination case, returning 2.
    - The return will be 2*2 = 4.
  - `B(2, 2)` is a termination case, returning 2.
  - The return will be 4*2 = 8.

Comment: I see, I wasn't sure how to account for the special cases where n=1 ,n=2. Can you explain how the recursion works by using the "return B..." method?

Comment: @user2359675 Recursion is simply a function calling itself, which is what happens here.  The function calls itself twice, with a lower value of `n` each time.  I have amended my answer with an example invocation.